# Node.js JDBC - How to run with a portable JRE

Tags: java, node.js, express, jdbc

I started to develop a simple application with express.js and node.jdbc. This node-jdbc uses node java and this depends on the installed JDK on my machine.
To make my little try independent from the environment I want to use a portable JRE within my bundle.

So is there a possibility to include and use a portable JRE for the node-jdbc?
And how can it be done?

Comment: Define "portable JRE". What are you expecting to do (and probably more important: not have to do)?

Comment: I did a small JDBC Connector to MySQL with this node-jdbc. I did the compilation on my local machine. Now I want to distribute this connector to 3 service machines. These machines are not very configurable, so I want to have a portable JRE inside my package, to be sure that JRE 1.8 is used.

Comment: So through what process do you distribute to the service machines?

Comment: I just want to copy my sources. Later I want to use maybe enclose.js.